# Create cluster with Shared Network in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, networking, google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I’m trying to create a cluster in GKE project-1 with shared network of project-2.

Roles given to Service account:
project-1: Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin, Compute Network Admin, Kubernetes Engine Host Service Agent User
project-2: Kubernetes Engine Service Agent, Compute Network User, Kubernetes Engine Host Service Agent User

Service Account is created under project-1.
API & Services are enabled in both Projects.

But I am getting this error persistently.
Error: googleapi: Error 403: Kubernetes Engine Service Agent is missing required permissions on this project. See Troubleshooting  |  Kubernetes Engine Documentation  |  Google Cloud for more info: required “container.hostServiceAgent.use” permission(s) for “projects/project-2”., forbidden

```
data "google_compute_network" "shared_vpc" {
    name = "network-name-in-project-2"
    project = "project-2"
}

 
data "google_compute_subnetwork" "shared_subnet" {
    name = "subnet-name-in-project-2"
    project = "project-2"
    region = "us-east1"
}

 # cluster creation under project 1
 # project 1 specified in Provider 
resource "google_container_cluster" "mowx_cluster" {
    name = var.cluster_name
    location = "us-east1"
    initial_node_count = 1
 
    master_auth {
        username = ""
        password = ""
 
        client_certificate_config {
            issue_client_certificate = false
        }
    }
 
    remove_default_node_pool = true
    cluster_autoscaling {
        enabled = false
    }
 
    # cluster_ipv4_cidr = var.cluster_pod_cidr
    ip_allocation_policy {
        cluster_secondary_range_name = "pods"
        services_secondary_range_name = "svc"
    }
 
    network = data.google_compute_network.shared_vpc.id
    subnetwork = data.google_compute_subnetwork.shared_subnet.id
}
```

Comment: I think the key point you are missing: the Kubernetes Engine Service Agent  needs the permission. This is a special type of service account assigned to Google Cloud services.

Comment: I added the service account (with name Google APIs Service Agent) of project 1 under project 2 and gave these two roles.  
1. Compute network User 2. Kubernetes Engine Host Service Agent User  
but I am still getting the error.

Comment: where can i find or create "Kubernetes Engine Service Agent for Project 1"? There are only two auto generate service accounts under project 1 IAM: 1. Compute Engine default service account 2. Google APIs Service Agent

Comment: Service Accounts are listed under IAM -> Service Accounts. To change a Service Agent's roles, sometimes you must manually add the Service Agent email address to IAM. The documentation discusses this in detail.

Comment: So, only when you create a gke cluster via gcloud command, it auto creates "Kubernetes Engine Service Agent for Project 1". And then you can use terraform to create cluster.

Comment: I cannot answer your last question. I use Terraform and the GCP CLI every day, but I only create K8s clusters via the Console GUI a couple of times per year. My comments are regarding how IAM and service accounts operate. Take my comments above as hints on what you need to research.

Comment: Another tip is Shared VPC. This requires more permissions (role). That is the source of your error/problem.

Comment: As you are missing one Role: "Kubernetes Engine Host Service Agent User" (roles/container.hostServiceAgentUser). Checking the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles), it seems that this Role is the only one with the permission "container.hostServiceAgent.use", that is requested by the operation you are performing.

Comment: @Mahboob I have assigned this Role to the service account already.

Comment: @JohnHanley the issue is resolved. "Kubernetes Engine Service Agent for Project 1" service account was not auto generated which was causing the issue in the first place. Your tip helped a lot. thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer based on the discussion in the comments and posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

The error you encountered:

```
Error: googleapi: Error 403: Kubernetes Engine Service Agent is missing required permissions on this project. See Troubleshooting | Kubernetes Engine Documentation | Google Cloud for more info: required “container.hostServiceAgent.use” permission(s) for “projects/project-2”., forbidden
```

means that the necessary service agent was not created:

`roles/container.serviceAgent` - Kubernetes Engine Service Agent:

> Gives Kubernetes Engine account access to manage cluster resources.
> Includes access to service accounts.

The official [troubleshooting docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted) describe a solution for such problems:

> To resolve the issue, if you have removed the `Kubernetes Engine Service Agent` role from your Google Kubernetes Engine service account,
> add it back. Otherwise, you must re-enable the Kubernetes Engine API,
> which will correctly restore your service accounts and permissions.
> You can do this in the gcloud tool or the Cloud Console.

The solution above works as in your use case the account was missing so it had to be (re)created.

Answer (score 0):

For me, even though the gke serice account existed and had the roles `Kubernetes Engine Host Service Agent` and `Kubernetes Engine Service Agent` in the both the service and host projects, I still got the 443 error.

The problem was that the service account needed to have `roles/compute.networkUser` and `roles/compute.instanceAdmin` applied to the VPC's subnetwork binding of the VPC.

See: resource `google_compute_subnetwork_iam_binding`
See also `module "shared_vpc_access"`

Answer (score 0):

The steps I followed to resolve the same issue:

##### On the service project level:

1. Check **Kubernetes Engine API** enabled on the service
   project
2. Check both service accounts are created by clicking on the `Include Google-provided role grants` option in the upper-right corner of the Google IAM console

   1. GKE service acc (*service-SERVICE_PROJECT_NUM@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com*)
   2. Google API service acc (*SERVICE_PROJECT_NUM@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com*)

##### On the host project level:

1. Check **Kubernetes Engine API** enabled on the host
   project
2. Grant the GKE service acc shown above the `roles/container.hostServiceAgentUser` and `roles/compute.networkUser` roles
3. Grant the Google API service acc shown above the `roles/compute.networkUser` role

This will allow the Kubernetes Engine service account to configure shared network resources at the host project level for clusters created in service projects

Note: IAM role binding can also be added on a subnet-level permission